# how to solve this attachment functionality

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, salesforce1-app

i faced a problem in salesforce,
i want to get userId from localstorage and input type= file value {file is jpg/png}
and then put them into apex class as a parameter via apex action function. but the error is found missing body in attachment file.

my apex code and visualforce page is below..

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page Controller="attachmentsample"> 
<apex:form >
    <apex:outputPanel id="out">
        <p>
            see after effects
        </p>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!SaveMYdoc}" name="showMYupload" reRender="out">
        <apex:param assignTo="{!file}" name="uvalue" value=""/>
        <apex:param assignTo="{!uLoginId}" name="uId" value=""/>        
    </apex:actionFunction>
  <apex:sectionHeader title="Upload a Attachment into Salesforce"/>
  <apex:pageblock >
      <apex:pageblocksection columns="1">
          <input type="file" id="upid" name="myfile"/>
          <button id="save" onclick="attach(); return false;">save</button>

      </apex:pageblocksection>
  </apex:pageblock> 
</apex:form> 

    <script>
    function attach(){
        var uvalue = document.getElementById("upid").files[0].name; 
        var uId = localStorage.getItem("userId");
        console.log(uId);
        showMYupload(uvalue, uId);    
    }
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

Apex Class:

```
public class attachmentsample {
    public String uLoginId {get; set;}
    public blob file {get; set;}

    public attachmentsample(){
      Attachment attach = new Attachment();

    }

    Public void SaveMYdoc()
    {
        system.debug('My user id'+ uLoginId);
        Attachment attach = new Attachment();
        attach.ParentId = uLoginId;
        attach.Name = 'zero';
        attach.Body = file;        
        insert attach;   
    }   


    }
```